# rvest handling hidden text

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, hidden-field

I don't see the data/text I am looking for when scraping a web page

I tried googling the issue without having any luck. I also tried using the xpath but i get `{xml_nodeset (0)}`

```
require(rvest)
url <- "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/ipos"
IPOS <- read_html(url)
IPOS %>% xml_nodes("tbody") %>% xml_text()
```

Output:

```
[1] "\n            \n          \n          \n            \n          \n        "
```

I do not see any of the IPO data. Expected output should contain the table for the "Priced" IPOs: Symbol, Company Name, etc...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the table data are loaded by scripts. You can use `RSelenium` package to get them.

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(port = 1210L, browser = "firefox", check = FALSE)
remDr <- rD$client

url <- "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/ipos"
remDr$navigate(url)

IPOS <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

str(IPOS)

PRICED <- IPOS[[3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for the expensive RSelenium. There is an API call you can find in the network tab returning everything as json.

For example,

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/ipo/calendar?date=2019-09')

View(data$data$priced$rows)
```

[image]